# Timeout with wireguard in docker

Tags: networking, docker, wireguard

I have wireguard running in a container on a cloud-based VM.  I can see udp traffic on the ethernet interface in the VM and container.

But when the wireguard interface is enabled, the client that's trying to connect to it has no traffic.

## Relevant info:

### Client (vm on home network):

Results of `wg`:

```
interface: wg0
  public key: gDOtdK3Fim9fSBZWss7tfCsCsIgr5wrAwpszkyNjuQE=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 45821
  fwmark: 0xca6c

peer: OEPlqXd3gOzbQhnAA0lZkLZ+/cf365JRlVUAaxoX6Ug=
  endpoint: redactedIPv4:51820
  allowed ips: 0.0.0.0/0
  transfer: 0 B received, 21.97 KiB sent
```

`wg0.conf` on client

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = redacted
Address = 10.13.13.100
DNS = 10.13.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = OEPlqXd3gOzbQhnAA0lZkLZ+/cf365JRlVUAaxoX6Ug=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = redactedIPv4:51820
```

### Cloud based VM that's running the container

Results of `docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                  COMMAND      CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS           NAMES
885feaa34c1d   cr.cclloyd.com/cclloyd/wgtest:latest   "/s6-init"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour (healthy)   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:51820->51820/udp, :::51820->51820/udp   wgtest
```

### Container

Results of `wg` command:

```
interface: IdQUQ527
  public key: 1uhRlqmJCqVrxJkx2BUon3gu5w4lUZmE9z7vP4vafzk=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: OEPlqXd3gOzbQhnAA0lZkLZ+/cf365JRlVUAaxoX6Ug=
  allowed ips: 10.13.13.100/32
```

Config inside container:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.13.0.1/16
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = redacted


[Peer]
PublicKey = OEPlqXd3gOzbQhnAA0lZkLZ+/cf365JRlVUAaxoX6Ug=
AllowedIPs = 10.13.13.100/32
```

Results of `tcpdump -n udp`

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
22:09:33.014069 IP redacted.10717 > 172.21.0.2.51820: UDP, length 148
22:09:38.292409 IP redacted.10717 > 172.21.0.2.51820: UDP, length 148
22:09:43.412137 IP redacted.10717 > 172.21.0.2.51820: UDP, length 148
```

Answer (score 0):

Your keys don't match. The `[Peer]` section of the client config needs to be configured with the public key of the server:

```
[Peer]
PublicKey = 1uhRlqmJCqVrxJkx2BUon3gu5w4lUZmE9z7vP4vafzk=
```

And the `[Peer]` section of the server config needs to be configured with the public key of the client:

```
[Peer]
PublicKey = gDOtdK3Fim9fSBZWss7tfCsCsIgr5wrAwpszkyNjuQE=
```